# Default template ASP.NET Core Web Application don’t run “Self-Contained”

Tags: visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0

I have created an ASP.NET Core Web Application (Asp.NET Core 2.0, Web Application) with Visual Studio 2017 15.7.5.
I further have configure a “publish profile” with publish method “File System”, Configuration: “Release”, Target Framework: “netcoreapp2.0”, Deployment Mode: “Self-Contained”, Target Runtime: “win-x86”.

The project was created without problems (I don’t have done any change) and does run in debug mode with IIS Express without problems.
If I deploy it, an "app".exe is created, I can start it and then see the console:

> Hosting environment: Production
>   Content root path: "path"\publish
>   Now listening on http://localhost:5000

But, if I access http://localhost:5000 from browser, I can see error messages in the console like:

> fail: Request matched multiple actions resulting in ambiguity.
>   Matching actions: Page: / Index   fail: An unhandled exception has
>   occurred: Multiple actions matched.
>   The following actions matched
>   route data and had all constraints satisfied:
>    Page: / Index
>    Page: / index

Whereby the browser shows http error 404 (not found) or 500 (server error).

So (for me) it seems as the selfhosting works principally, as the “web server” can be reached, but something goes wrong in the deployment...

What do I have to do to bring the selfhosting to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as I have found the issue:
By the deploy, additional files **{AppName}.PrecompiledViews.dll** and {AppName}.PrecompiledViews.pdb were generated by VS2017 and copied in the publish directory, that have caused the problem (multiple definitions).
After I have deleted the files, the selfhosting works now...
I don’t know, why the files were deployed - if I redeploy the app, it seems as the files are not generated again - so it maybe is an issue with (only) the first deploy...

Answer (score 0):

there is issue in routing middleware which is only uses controller and action tokens to map/execute an action, thereby if you have a few actions within a controller with the same name - it will throw an ambiguous exception.

To resolve this issue, you can start use `[HttpGet]`, `[HttpPost]`, etc. or `[Route]` attributes

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't understand what you mean. As I worte, the app run's with IIS Express without problems - the issue occurs only after deploy and start as self hosted app. I think, I have found the reason (see my posting below).